# Oracle DB Setup in VDI

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, vdi

I have installed Oracle 11g in my VDI. How can i configure my listener.ora and tnsnames.ora so that the DB in my VDI can be accessed using other VDIs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you need any special configuration in listener.ora/tnsnames.ora. Use a bridged network (so that the guest gets an IP address on the network) with a fixed IP address and you should be more or less done.

Comment: Fixed IP yes, but are you using a bridged network? And do you have a firewall? What virtualization platform are you running? VirtualBox, VMWare, other?

Comment: Using VMWare. Since it is the office network, yes, it has firerwall

Comment: Is it running in VMWare on your computer or in a VMWare server somewhere?

Comment: It is running in server VM